# Run ActiveRecord migrations without Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to update a gem called [`textacular`](https://github.com/textacular/textacular/pull/121/files) to be compatible with latest rails version.

In the development Rake-tasks we need to run a few ActiveRecord migrations - without Rails.

Today it looks like:

```
namespace :migrate do
    desc 'Run the test database migrations'
    task :up => :'db:connect' do
      ActiveRecord::Migrator.up 'db/migrate'
    end

    desc 'Reverse the test database migrations'
    task :down => :'db:connect' do
      ActiveRecord::Migrator.down 'db/migrate'
    end
end
```

However when using ActiveRecord >= 5, it fails with:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'up' for ActiveRecord::Migrator:Class`.

I have tried to look through the source code for ActiveRecord, tried a bunch of different methods but have not managed to run the migrations.

Does anyone have a hint of what to do?

**Edit**

*Using `ActiveRecord::Migration.up` does nothing, probably just `returns` based on the method.*

*Using `ActiveRecord::Migration.migrate(:up)` gives output:*

```
==  ActiveRecord::Migration: migrating ========================================
==  ActiveRecord::Migration: migrated (0.0000s) ===============================
```

All migrations are in the folder `db/migrate`.

Comment: Which Rails version are you using with Migration-class exactly?

Comment: Not using Rails at all, only using `activerecord (5.1.5)` at the moment. @AndresEhrenpreis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this (until Rails 6 is release at least), the implementation can be seen on [textacular](https://github.com/textacular/textacular/blob/master/Rakefile#L45)

```
task :up => :'db:connect' do
  migrations = if ActiveRecord.version.version >= '5.2'
    ActiveRecord::Migration.new.migration_context.migrations
  else
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations('db/migrate')
  end
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.new(:up, migrations, nil).migrate
end
```

Not very satisfied with this solution, but this was the only way I could get the migrations to run on Rails 5, 5.1 and 5.2.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this command:

```
ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new(Rails.root.join('db', 'migrate'), ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration).migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the [rails github page](https://github.com/rails/rails) then starting from [Rails 5.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/5-2-stable) the [Migrator class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L1159) is cut down quite a bit. Much of its methods have moved to [Migration class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L516) instead (including the [.up method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L773)).

Therefore just replace `ActiveRecord::Migrator` with `ActiveRecord::Migration`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I have tried this approach, but alas, no migrations are completed.
I added the outputs to my original question.